# .htaccess Redirect Only Specific UTF-8 SubDomain U. R. L.s to Its SubDomain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, utf-8, http-status-code-301

I have:

```
https://Restoran.Grupacija.com/?ćumur
```

Which needs to be redirected to:

```
https://Restoran.Grupacija.com/
```

This directive is in .htaccess file in the Root Folder, but it does not work:

```
Redirect 301 "^/%3Fćumur" https://Restoran.Grupacija.com
```

I have also tried this, but it does not work either:

```
Redirect 301 "^/%3F%C4%87umur" https://Restoran.Grupacija.com
```

My .htaccess file *is* UTF-8 already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mod_alias `Redirect` directive matches the URL-path only, which notably excludes the query string. (However, neither does the `Redirect` directive match using a regex, it uses simple prefix-matching instead.)

To match the query string you need to use mod_rewrite instead and match against the `QUERY_STRING` server variable in a `RewriteCond` directive.

Note that the browser/user-agent will URL encode the `ć` as `%C4%87` in the HTTP request and the `QUERY_STRING` server variable is not %-decoded, so we need to match the encoded request. Strictly speaking, both `%C4` and `%c4` are valid encodings.

I'm assuming you don't need to explicitly check the requested hostname, unless this query string could be valid on another hostname that your server receives?

For example, to perform the redirect as requested, the following would need to go near the top of your `.htaccess` file before any existing rewrites.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^%[cC]4%87umur$
RewriteRule ^$ / [QSD,R=301,L]
```

The `QSD` (Query String Discard) flag removes the query string from the redirect response.

Test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues.

(You do not need to repeat the `RewriteEngine` directive if this already occurs in your `.htaccess` file.)

Comment: Thank you. I will accept this as a valid answer. Can you tell just something else more: namely, how to do the same with `/?pevać`? The letter `ć` being the last one in a word?

Comment: @De1an To match the query string `pevać` only you would modify the regex like so: `^peva%[cC]4%87$`. To match either `ćumur` _or_  `pevać` in a single regex use: `^%[cC]4%87umur|peva%[cC]4%87$` (using regex _alternation_).

Comment: I just checked this. Works perfectly. Thank you again. I literally checked every Googled result on StackOverflow for this problem and none matches/matched this exact one. I am truly grateful to you.